# How to repeat a line that works

Tags: javascript

I'am new with javascript and this is my question, I have made this script and I want to repeat the line with "onmouseover, mouseout and mousedown" but when I do it does not work anymore, where do I go wrong here. Thank you.

```
<script>

            function RandomSwapDown() {                 
                document.Rita.src = '4.gif';    
            }                               
            function SwapBack() {       
                document.Rita.src = 'mouse_over.png';           
            }
            function SwapOut() {
                document.Rita.src = 'mouse_normal.png';
            }   

</script>

</html>

<div style='top: 200px; left: 175px; position: absolute;'>

<img src='mouse_normal.png'  onMouseOver='SwapBack()' onMouseOut= 'SwapOut()' onMouseDown = 'RandomSwapDown()' img name='Rita'  width="121" height="146" >

</div>
```

Comment: These are functions. How are you calling them?

Comment: and What `Rita` is? can you show your html and js ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Hello, I am missing the rest of my text, I did put it in my question, sorry :s

Comment: Thanks, it realy works, is there a way to make x.src random for 3 images when I use "function RandomSwapDown(x)". Thank you :)

Comment: If the answer worked, please select as answer for your question. In regards to your new question, are you trying to randomly show three images?

Comment: Thank you, and yes I'm trying to show three images randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

            function RandomSwapDown(x) {                 
                x.src = '4.gif';    
            }                               
            function SwapBack(x) {       
                x.src = 'mouse_over.png';           
            }
            function SwapOut(x) {
                x.src = 'mouse_normal.png';
            }   

</script>

</html>

<div style='top: 200px; left: 175px; position: absolute;'>

<img src='mouse_normal.png'  onMouseOver='SwapBack(this)' onMouseOut= 'SwapOut(this)' onMouseDown = 'RandomSwapDown(this)' width="121" height="146" >

</div>
```